# Пропуск слова не мешает восприятию текста?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Треугольник в богословии – символ Святой Троицы. **Со слов святого
>   Иринея Лионского, в своём графическом начертании означает**: Бог стал
>   человеком – это **треугольник, опускающийся вниз**, чтобы человек стал
>   богом – это треугольник вершиной вверх. И это чередование –
>   демонстрация нам идеи самоподобия. Мир, в каждом сегменте которого –
>   Бог. А ещё этот круг в такой короне похож на светило, так
>   представляется солнце на детском рисунке, на языке архетипа.

Comment: Автор почему-то не хочет пойти путём иллюстрирования, но здесь художественное слово бессильно: круги в кругах, треугольники Серпинского и треугольник в богословии... (правильнее — в христианской символике). Ужас.

Comment: Это пишется наспех, почти черновик. Будет ещё и научный редактор и доправка по моим замечаниям.

Comment: М_Г назвал одним словом этот «наспех-стиль». Деликатный наш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Мир, в каждом сегменте которого – Бог.   **Мир, где Бог – в каждом сегменте.**

2) **Бог стал человеком – это треугольник, опустившийся вниз,  а  человек стал богом – это треугольник вершиной вверх.**

Comment: Треугольник сдвинулся со своего места? :))

Comment: Может быть, подойдет "направленный вниз" (вершиной), "смотрящий вниз"?

Comment: Это художественный текст, и треугольник, опустившийся вниз (изображенный вершиной вниз), - это Бог, опустившийся на землю.

Comment: По-моему, по одну сторону тире — некий символ, а по другую — его художесвенное и прочее восприятие. Описание символа должно быть более или менее точным.

Comment: Не должно быть повторов и симметричных конструкций, это плохо воспринимается на слух.

Answer (score 1):

Перлы:

графическое начертание

своё начертание

в начертании означает

Бог стал человеком – это треугольник. Вариант исправления: "треугольник вершиной вниз — Бог стал человеком" (тире вместо слова *символизирует*).

чтобы человек стал богом – это треугольник. Вариант исправления:  "треугольник вершиной вверх — человек стал Богом"

**Со слов святого Иринея Лионского, этот орнамент означает: Бог стал человеком (треугольник, устремленный вниз), чтобы человек стал Богом (треугольник вершиной вверх).**

демонстрация нам идеи

этот круг в такой короне (какой круг, в какой короне?)

треугольник опускающийся (пришедший в движение?). Может быть, подойдет "направленный вниз" (вершиной), "смотрящий вниз"?

P.S. Определитесь, Бог у вас с какой буквы пишется.